# How do I print an array in AutoHotkey?

Tags: arrays, autohotkey

I have a set of arrays in AutoHotkey which I want to display as strings for debugging.

```
strArray := ["Alice", "Mary", "Bob"] ; 1D array
strArray2D := [[1,2,3], [4,5,6]]     ; 2D array
```

In Java, Javascript, and AutoIt I can accomplish this with the built-in toString() functions.

```
strArray.toString();            // JavaScript: "Alice,Mary,Bob"
Arrays.toString(strArray);      // Java:       "[Alice, Mary, Bob]"
_ArrayToString($strArray, ", ")  ; AutoIt:     "Alice, Mary, Bob"
```

AHK's developer lexikos has stated a built-in function for displaying arrays [will not be added anytime soon](https://autohotkey.com/boards/viewtopic.php?p=85461#p85461), and most of the solutions I've found online [seem fairly complex](https://autohotkey.com/board/topic/70490-print-array/?p=492678).

**How can I print an array in AutoHotkey?**

Comment: This one https://autohotkey.com/board/topic/70490-print-array/?p=492728 from the link you posted is quite simple and can print arrays with any depth.

Answer (score 7):

**This converts 1 and 2 dimension arrays to strings**

```
F2:: MsgBox % join(["Alice", "Mary", "Bob"])
F3:: MsgBox % join2D([[1,2,3], [4,5,6]])


join( strArray )
{
  s := ""
  for i,v in strArray
    s .= ", " . v
  return substr(s, 3)
}

join2D( strArray2D )
{
  s := ""
  for i,array in strArray2D
    s .= ", [" . join(array) . "]"
  return substr(s, 3)
}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Why does the function return a substring?

Comment: to trim a leading delimiter if present